# Prevent intersecting of meshes while animating

Tags: animation, mesh

I have always had the problem of meshes intersecting with the surrounding meshes while animating.

For example, while I make a human mesh kick a ball, the leg goes through the mesh and it takes a lot of time to fix this because I have to do it manually.

Please suggest ways to prevent meshes from intersecting while animating.